# Render page more flexible

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my current project, have a assumption that a lot of different UI will be required.

ex> there will be two clients, boogle and yumhoo, these two client want totally different view.

I made a prototype like this,

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  after_action :render_ui
  def index
  end

  def render_ui
    render "#{self.controller_name}/#{ENV['CLIENT_UI']}/#{self.action_name}"
  end
end
```

my plan was to generate the path to the view file dynamically,

but there is a big problem here,

as you all know rails automatically runs,

```
render 'there own contoller and action name combination'
```

and throws an error,

```
Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action
```

Is there a way to `skip the default automatic render feature` in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`after_action` is called when the view has already been rendered. If you want to render a specific file, simply call render in the action itself.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render "#{self.controller_name}/#{ENV['CLIENT_UI']}/#{self.action_name}"
  end
end
```

You may also want to consider to use the [Rails 4.1 template variants](http://codemy.net/posts/rails-4-1-variants) feature.

Comment: But I don't want to put that line in to every action :(

Comment: Wrap it into an utility method and call the method. Or use the variant feature as I told you. You set the variant (the client) in a before filter, and delegate the template negotiation to Rails.